# MySQL UPDATE "Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE .... does not exist"

Tags: mysql

When running the following code on MySQL workbench, see the

```
Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE .... does not exist
```

I don't know why it occurs for below code

```
UPDATE sscSerials s JOIN sscProduct p ON s.productID = p.ProductID 
SET s.status = 'Deleted' 
WHERE p.isActive = 0 AND p.name like '%aquatech%';
```

Comment: share full stacktrace of error.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is causing it.

Comment: Check if there are update triggers in the tables involved, and please post the complete error message: it contains the name of the procedure the server is looking for

Comment: How is it possible to trace an error from this limited details?